# How to traverse the complex nested Json in C# and append the some set of values in the same Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, recursion, json.net

I need to traverse the below and form the final output with an additional set of values added in the same JSON model. Please help me how to add as the data contains recursively.

Order of Keys should not be modified. The final output should be the same format.
I would like to deserialize this JSON into some classes, update the some more data and then later serialize it back to JSON. How can we do it?

Read from Json File:
Input:

```
      {
  "id" : "abv.123",
  "developName" : "ABV.123",
  "pay25" : {
    "0" : {
      "data" : "group35",
      "divison" : 0,
      "pay25" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "name33"        
        }
      }
    },
    "1" : {
      "data" : "group35",
      "divison" : 0,
      "pay25" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "group35",
          "divison" : 0,
          "pay25" : {
            "0" : {
              "data" : "label",
              "divison" : 0,
              "text" : "name55",
              "color1" : "green"
            }
          }
        },
        "1" : {
          "data" : "group35",
          "divison" : 0,
          "pay25" : {
            "0" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "fab125"

            },
            "1" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "gbt333"
            },
            "2" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test53"
            },
            "3" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test55"
            },
            "4" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "teds422"
            },
            "5" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test66"
            },
            "6" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test982"
            },
            "7" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test322"
            },
            "8" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test633"
            },
            "9" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test622"
            },
            "10" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test733"
            },
            "11" : {
              "data" : "divisiondata",
              "divison" : 0,
              "divName" : "test71"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "2" : {
      "data" : "group35",
      "divison" : 0,
      "pay25" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test9134234",
          "deps1" : [ {
            "datadiv123" : [ "1", "2" ],
            "value" : true
          } ]
        },
        "1" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test898932"
        },
        "2" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "tewst432"
        }
      }
    },
    "3" : {
      "data" : "group35",
      "divison" : 0,
      "pay25" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test352322",
           "deps1" : [ {
            "datadiv123" : [ "test", "tesstt" ],
            "value" : true
          } ]
        },
        "1" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test523432"
        },
        "2" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test634fdg"
        },
        "3" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "tssg32432",
          "validators" : [ {
            "data" : "integer"
          } ]
        },
        "4" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test1111"
        },
        "5" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test2222"
        }
      }
    },
    "4" : {
      "data" : "group35",
      "divison" : 0,
      "pay25" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test55632"
        }
      }
    },
    "5" : {
      "data" : "dynamicgrouptable",
      "operation" : [ "add", "delete" ],
      "dynamicValue" : {
        "0" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test953312"
        },
        "1" : {
         "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test953312622"
        },
        "2" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test9533126499"
        },
        "3" : {
          "data" : "divisiondata",
          "divison" : 0,
          "divName" : "test953312644"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Read the additional set of values from this JSON:

```
    {
    "name33": {
        "def1": "Value 1",
        "tip3": "Tip 53",
        "disp3": "develop 1",
        "path" : "Displayname"

    },
    "fab125": {
        "def1": "Value 5",
        "tip3": "strr11",
        "disp3": "develop 2",
        "path" : "Displayname"
    },
    "test322": {
        "def1": "Value 2",
        "tip3": "dev 53",
        "disp3": "develop 3",
        "path" : "Displayname"

    },
    {....},
{.....},
"test953312": {
        "def1": "Value 21",
        "tip3": "dev 5311",
        "disp3": "develop 334",
        "path" : "Displayname"

    },
    "test953312622": {
        "def1": "Value 212",
        "tip3": "dev 53222",
        "disp3": "develop 22113",
        "path" : "Displayname"

    },
    {....}

}
```

The output should be merged with both json without changing the order of data:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

You could use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` of `Newtonsoft.Json` to trevasal the data. Since your data is not regular, deserialize it is more complicated. It may not output extra fields.

```cs
   //deserialize
   JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
   JObject idObj = (JObject)jObj["id"];
   JObject idObj0 = (JObject)idObj["0"]["id"]["0"]; // 0 can replace to N, loop can deal with it.
   idObj0.add("value", "ewr");
   idObj0.add("type", "bool");
   //serialize
   string resultJsonString = jObj.ToString();
```

Reference: [Json.NET Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm)

#### Solution 2:

If you prefer to deserialize into a class. you could use the native library `System.Text.Json` in .Net 5 or .Net Core 3.1

```cs
      public class Model
      {
          public string reports {get; set;};
          public Dictionary<string, IdModel> id {get; set;};
      }

      public class IdModel
      {
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string data {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string text {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string name {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string display {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string value {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public string type {get; set;}
           [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
           public Dictionary<string, IdModel> id {get; set;};
      }

      var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(jsonString);
      data.id["0"].id["0"].value = "ewr";
      data.id["0"].id["0"].type = "bool";
      .......
      string resultJsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Model>(data);
```

Reference: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#code-samples)

I will choose solution 1, because of the complicated data.

Here is the code you could reference

```cs
     using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

     var inputJObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
     var appendDataJObject = JObject.Parse(appendDataString);

     FindAndReplace(inputJObject, appendDataJObject);

     string resultString = inputJObject.ToString();

     public static void FindAndReplace(
          JObject input, 
          JObject appendData, 
          string keyName = "pay25", 
          string toReplaceFieldName = "divName")
     {
          foreach (var targetKey in ((JObject)input[keyName]))
          {
               var targetJObject = (JObject)targetKey.Value;

               //check whether there is pay25 property in child, if yes, search child recursively
               if (targetJObject.ContainsKey(keyName))
               {
                    FindAndReplace(targetJObject, appendData);
               }
               else
               {
                    //if no, check divName property existence
                    if (targetJObject.ContainsKey(toReplaceFieldName))
                    {
                         string divName = (string)targetJObject[toReplaceFieldName];
                         //check whether there is data has key = divName
                         if (appendData.ContainsKey(divName))
                         {
                              //append data
                              foreach (var data in (JObject)appendData[divName])
                              {
                                   targetJObject.Add(data.Key, data.Value);
                              }
                          }
                     }
                }
           }
      }
```

Finally, I think it is a question of how to replace data recursively.

Comment: "  var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(jsonString);
      data.id["0"].id["0"].value = "ewr";
      data.id["0"].id["0"].type = "bool"; " ---> I see here we are appending the values for [0].value. But, we dont know how many keys would be present such that  data.id["0"].id["0"].value = "ewr";
      data.id["0"].id["0"].type = "bool"; " data.id["0"].id["1"].value = "ewr";
      data.id["0"].id["2"].type = "bool"; " or " data.id["1"].id["1"].value = "ewr"; The object is not a static one, Each json can have mutiple values  inside "Id" and nested  "id" as well

Comment: Actually, id values of "solution 2" can be nested, and with unknown number of id, if you could explain how do you plan to assign value, I could provide more information.

Comment: I have edited the proper json value from both input files and what is the expected json  output, thanks

Comment: Grad to hear that.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you could check again.

Comment: Thank you Epic Chen, Will validate the same and one doubt targetJObject would be returning jobject which we can serialize and store into JSON file, correct?

Comment: string resultString = inputJObject.ToString(); is serialization, so you can do any what you want to do, if you have a certain understanding of serialization.

Comment: Thanks, There is a use case which i have added in the input/output(above question) if you see "5": as different data Name, How do we handle with the above code? Is that possible can be parsed one more key in arguments?

Comment: You could change the keyName  parameter to array or list, then you will be able to use loop to check with them.

Comment: Is it possible to update the Answer with this final scenario so that it would be a generic way even if we have multiple key names available

Comment: You could do that by yourself at first. That would help you figure out that  how to extend the code in the future. If you still do not figure out for a period of time. I could provide the answer for you.

Comment: public static void FindAndReplace(
          JObject input, 
          JObject appendData, 
          List<string> KeyNames, 
          string toReplaceFieldName = "divName"){ While iterating foreach (var targetKey in ((JObject)input[keyName]))
          {}  } ,We need to check if the list of keyNames existing in Input, but since it is jobject, How we can check if exists?

Comment: //check whether there is pay25 property in child, if yes, search child recursively
               if (targetJObject.ContainsKey(keyName)), you could refer this logic at above code.

Comment: I have a follow-up question for the json which we got  to map the each key with static json file and convert into one more json. Can i post it here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233316/discussion-between-epic-chen-and-fosk).

Comment: Okay Done. Will have a discussion there

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use  Newtonsoft.Json it's, it's the most used library in C#.
So, first of all, you would need to create a model for what your data.
I would assume would look like this:

```
public class MyModel{
public List<MyModel> id {get;set;}
.....
}
public class MyTopLevelModel : MyModel{
public string reports{get;set;}
}
```

So you can do this:

```
MyTopLevelModel myTopLevelModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTopLevelModel>(json);
//then get the place where you want to place the extra data like 
myTopLevelModel.id[0].id[0].value = "whatever"
```

After that you can use

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTopLevelModel);
```